# How to cut the main text in the cell with Right Detail style?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a cell with Right Detail style and when the label text is too big the detail label turns into ... but I need the detail text always to be on screen and the label main text should be cut if it is too big. How can I implement this without changing the style of the cell?

[image: prototype cell]

I need to make the detail value to be shown fully in the cell - and on the screenshot is the present situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the UILabel yourself, to force it to be a fixed size ? The default code apple provide seems to be resizing it automagically.

CGFrame oldLabelFrame = cell.textLabel.frame;

cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(oldLabelFrame.origin.x, oldLabelFrame.origin.y,400, oldLabelFrame.size.height); <--- change this

Of course making a custom cell would be better.

Comment: I don't need to resize the cell - I just want to cut the label text and not to cut the detail text. (I've edited the question)

Comment: but in my case I have cell.textLabel.frame.size.width is not assignable ... So I need to create the custom cell?

Comment: Edited my example above to show you how to change the width, making a custom cell may be easier :) as you can define the behaviour better.

Answer (score 0):

**Set the character length needed for the detail text.Check the text length of the detail text. and limits the text length count of the the label text according to your needs.**

```
NSString *labeltext=@"hai it's a beautiful place";
NSString * detailTextLabel=@"This is a test text for checking the detail text label";


if (detailTextLabel.length>14) {

    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",[labeltext substringToIndex:3]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text=detailTextLabel;

}
else{
///write what to do if detail text label is greater than 14 characters..

}
```